# React-router doesn't work well when loaded from a route instead of the home page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

We're using react 16.13 and react-router-dom 5.1.2 but we struggle to make it work the way we want:

- it works great when used with our https://react.domain.com/
- but it doesn't when a user starts the app directly on a subpage, https://react.domain.com/page1 as we can't find any way to tell react-router that the base url is still `/` and not `page1/`

(We've configured the nodejs/express backend to send the react app no matter the route)

So react-router just adds all the history / path to the `/page1` url, resulting in `/page1/login`, `/page1/page1`, etc. instead of the `/login` or `/page1` urls.

Is there any way to achieve that?
The goal is to allow the refresh of the page, and to allow direct access to a specific route.

EDIT: code example

**client side**

```
 <StoreProvider store={store}>
    <Suspense fallback={<MainPageFallback />}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Router basename={location.pathname}>
                <I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
                    <TryCatch>
                        <Navbar actions={<UserSettings />} />
                        <div className={classes.appContent}>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/start">
                                    <LandingPage />
                                </Route>
                                <Route exact path="/search">
                                    <SearchPlacePage />
                                </Route>
                                <Route exact path="/signup">
                                    <SignUpPage />
                                </Route>
                                <Route exact path="/signin">
                                    <LoginPage />
                                </Route>
                                <Route exact path="/forgot_password" component={ForgotPassword} />
                                <Redirect from="/*" to="/start" />
                            </Switch>

                            <Snackbar />
                        </div>
                    </TryCatch>
                </I18nextProvider>
            </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Suspense>
</StoreProvider>
```

**server side**

```
@Route('/*')
public async home({ query }: Request, res: Response) {
    const { resolve } = await import('path');
    const { readFileAsync } = await import('../Infrastructure/readFileAsync');
    try {
        const file = (await readFileAsync(resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'static', 'index.html')))
            .toString('utf-8');
        return res.send(file);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'static', 'notFound.html'));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: How are you running & serving the app? Where are you deploying it to? How the page requests are handled depends largely on the server environment. See CRA's [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs for a general sense.

Comment: The app will be deployed on AWS (elasticbeanstalk).
But we have the issue on the local environment as well (localhost, served with webpack or directly from nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Routes` rather than `Switch` for react-router-dom@6. Something like this:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I don't see how that would help

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@5`, so the `Switch` component is absolutely ok here.